# Recreate a text effect by adding a class to every text element

Tags: html, css

I want to have this beautiful text effect by adding a class to every text element:

[image]

Here is the original code of the above image.

https://codepen.io/pixy-dixy/pen/GRNwmWv

The issue with this code is he used attributes to create such a text effect but I want to use a simple class which can be added to any text element.

I tried to create that class with no luck:

Here is what I tried so far:

```css
.effect {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 400;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 5vw;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, red 25%, white 25%, white 50%, red 50%, red 75.2%, white 75%, white);
  background-size: 10px 10px;
  background-position: 0 0;
  mix-blend-mode: overlay;
  font-variation-settings: "GLOW" 1000;
  filter: invert(0.7) grayscale(1);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 2px 2px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), 1px 1px 1px rgba(138, 0, 0, 0.53), 1px 1px 1px white;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="effect">candy</h1>
```

Is there any solution to have a text element by adding a class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`text-shadow` cannot work well with `background-clip:text`. Use drop-shadow and adjust the code like below:

```css
.effect {
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 150px;
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, #c50000 0 5px, #c3c0c0 0 10px);
  filter:drop-shadow(4px 4px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.8));
}
```

```html
<h1 class="effect">candy</h1>
```

Comment: One more question, there is no way to change the white part of the text in your code? I changed the color but nothing changed!!

Comment: @SaraRee it's the gradient, you need to change the color of the gradient